# How to resolve the segmentation fault due to strtok()?

Tags: c

I am getting segmentation fault when the below line is executed:

```
result = strtok(data,delimiter);
```

I have given the backtrace :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x44359e85 in strtok () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x44359e85 in strtok () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x08048c02 in main () at multiply.c:36
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: How about giving us the code that fails?

Comment: Could you post your whole code? ...Also, is this on the FIRST time you execute strtok, or subsequent times? Because after the first time, you're supposed to use NULL as the first argument to strtok.

Answer (score 2):

There are few reasonable possibilities for the segmentation fault you have:

- Passing `NULL` as data in the first call to `strtok()`.
- Passing `NULL` as delimiter.
- Using a read-only string as data, which is forbidden, since `strtok()` modifies the source string.

I see you know how to use gdb, so put a break-point before the call to `strtok()` and see what values are passed to the function.

You can also use **valgrind**. It will help you to find the specific problem you have.

But, if you want better answers in stack-overflow, you must give some more code and other iformation.